# Menu displaying off screen on Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm having an issue with my wordpress menu which is not displaying in the desired position on mobile

http://savvyretiree.wpengine.com/category/investing/

Any help greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this rule *in a media query* for mobile to make it align right:

```
.menu-primary-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 47px;
}
```

Adjust the `margin-top` value as needed